# Where to start leaning VBA for excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to learn VBA for increasing my speed whicle working. I have come across various resources but i am not sure which one to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for many basic VBA tutorials.

http://www.excel-vba.com/excel-vba-solutions-beginners.htm gives the basics with examples. Try it out. You can also search in youtube for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have programming experience, I would suggest you buy a book for Excel VBA on Amazon.

There are two major part to learn:
1. VBA language itself
2. Excel object model : Workbook, Worksheet, Range, etc.